# Application running on wrong apache Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I created an application on Eclipse, locally on my PC. Once it was working I created a war file and deployed it to my Linux server. Now the problem is that the application is still running on my local Tomcat. I am not sure why this is happening.

Is there any place I can look to find the cause of this issue?
I created this application in JSP/servlet.

Comment: Did you stop the local Tomcat instance on PC? And please explain what exactly is the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks invalid , application can keep on running on your local PC and server both , its about which one you access i.e. which url you use in browser.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the application from running on your pc there are a lot of thing you can do to stop it.

1. If you are running windows and tomcat is installed as a service then you can stop the `Apache Tomcat` service by opening `services.msc`
2. You can also uninstall tomcat using $CATALINA_HOME/uninstall.exe
3. You can also access the tomcat's manager application and un-deploy your application. To do this go to `http://localhost:port/manager/html`. Enter the credentials you used during installation to log in. Find the application from the list there and stop it.

Answer (score 0):

You might check the running java vm by jvisualvm on your OS(with GUI). Or check the current running processes both in PC and linux server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not stopped the application running locally it will continue to run till you stop the tomcat server. Application can be packaged into a war file while tomcat is running.

If you have started the tomcat with in eclipse, use "Server" view in eclipse to stop the tomcat. If you have started tomcat via command line, you can use `shutdown.sh` or `shutdown.cmd` to stop the tomcat.